Maui CollectionView selected/hovered item rectangle has padding on Windows
See the attached screenshot:
We can see 4 items in a CollectionView, Item1 is selected, and Item2 is hovered, thus both are showing a grey rectangle:

The issue is that the rectangle has a very slight padding as you can clearly see (both horizontally and vertically).
What I am trying to do is to have this rectangle shown on the whole width/height of the item.
I have removed all the default control styles but have not been able to control this. Please not that VisualStates have a lot of issues and are not very reliable so I am trying in priority to figure out where the default appearance of the hovering/selection state is set.
Any help with this is appreciated, thank you.

Looks like it's the default style when selecting or hovering the item of a CollectionView on Windows, BTW, may I know what .NET version you are using?

Yes you are correct. I found the issue reported on the github and several related ones, regarding visual states. I didn't find a better workaround than adding a grid element on top of each list cell, and doing my own "is selected" mechanism with MVVM. I feel something could be done with Windows specific handlers but I have not tackled learning those yet unfortunately. I have 9.0.100-preview.2 workload installed and target .net8

For now, I think you can add a grid element on top of each list cell to fix it. You can also follow up the issue on the Github(you can edit it to your post).
